# Nested Insert Exec & DBCC INPUTBUFFER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to implement a trigger to audit the updates made to a table. In the trigger I create a temp table to store the results of a call to DBCC InputBuffer:

```
CREATE TABLE #inputbuffer (
 EventTypevarchar(255),
 Parametersint,
 EventInfovarchar(255)
 )

INSERT INTO #inputbuffer

exec('dbcc inputbuffer(' + @@spid + ') WITH NO_INFOMSGS ')
```

But there are a lot of SP's that make some Insert Exec statements and update the table with the trigger, so error 'An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.' is shown.

Is there a way to catch the results of inputbuffer other than an Insert Exec? `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` cannot be used because it requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission on the server for user who triggers trigger.

Comment: Consider using ready-made tools for this rather than reinventing the wheel. Such as SQL Audit or an XEvent trace. Doing this in triggers is going to get messy fast. `dm_exec_sql_text` is perfectly usable, you just need to do `EXECUTE AS`

Comment: You could execute the trigger in the context of a user with elevated privileges, eg `create trigger trg on tbl with execute as owner after update as ...`. But I don't think this would help, since `dm_exec_sql_text` will (I think) return the text *of the trigger*.